How to Create a List of Options and Highlight the Selected Options in Flutter?
I am attempting to create a page for a user's sign-up, where they select the weather they'd like to hike in, and put that option as part of their user information. I am only working with the front end of this and I do know that this may be a column of buttons with the different options.
The issue is, how do I change the color of the button upon selection and also de-change the color of other buttons?
I am quite new to flutter so, this page is based in a StatefulWidget, please

This is a snippet of my attempt. The code does not come close to the expected result:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:trailx_app/const/colors.dart';

class SignUpWeatherQ extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUpWeatherQ({super.key});

  @override
  _SignUpWeatherQ createState() => _SignUpWeatherQ();
}

class _SignUpWeatherQ extends State<SignUpWeatherQ> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Initialize any data or perform actions before the page is built
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up any resources or listeners when the widget is removed from the widget tree
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int selectedIndex = 0;
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: GridView.builder(
              physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 1),
              itemCount: 5,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ElevatedButton(
                  style: ButtonStyle(foregroundColor: ),
                  onPressed: () => setState(() {
                    selectedIndex = index;
                  }),
                  child: Text(
                    "Sunny",
                    style: GoogleFonts.getFont(
                      'Inter',
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: loginTextColor,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          letterSpacing: 0.6,
                          wordSpacing: 1,
                          fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            )));
  }

  // Define any other helper methods or callbacks
}



With the proper configuration, "selected" and "not selected" can be referenced using a MaterialStateProperty input for the button colors.

if I understand correctly, you need to create logic where the selected option will be displayed in a different color. You can achieve this by defining the selectedIndex and using it in the ButtonStyle. Here is an example:
class SignUpWeatherQ extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUpWeatherQ({super.key});

  @override
  _SignUpWeatherQ createState() => _SignUpWeatherQ();
}

class _SignUpWeatherQ extends State<SignUpWeatherQ> {
  int selectedIndex = -1; // No selection initially

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: GridView.builder(
          physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 1),
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            bool isSelected = selectedIndex == index;

            return ElevatedButton(
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                  isSelected ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey, // Change button color based on selection
                ),
                foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                  isSelected ? Colors.white : loginTextColor, // Change text color based on selection
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () => setState(() {
                selectedIndex = index; // Update selected index
              }),
              child: Text(
                "Sunny", // You can change this to dynamic content based on index
                style: GoogleFonts.getFont(
                  'Inter',
                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: isSelected ? Colors.white : loginTextColor,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    letterSpacing: 0.6,
                    wordSpacing: 1,
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



I see what you did, yes that is what I mean, I can see that now the button color changes upon selection and only one button is selected (highlighted) at a time. However, I came to notice that you used MaterialStateProperty, which is depreciated. Does that matter at all? What would the alternative be?
